# Should there be a comma between "every scrap" in the sentence below?

Tags: grammaticality, commas, comparatives

The following is a sentence I read in a novel called *Amy Snow*:

> I will carry out her wishes in death every scrap as faithfully as I did when she was with me.

The *every scrap* part confuses me — isn't there something wrong with it? Should there be a comma between it?

Comment: It's just another way of saying "every bit".

Comment: I agree with Kate; in fact the meaning is clearer with "bit" instead of "scrap". I'd say that "every scrap as faithfully as I did when she was with me" was a manner adjunct in clause structure. No real need for a comma.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly where you want to put commas. Can you show that?

Comment: I was thinking of placing a comma before "every" and after "scrap", but now I know that would be wrong as it was stated by tchrist and j_foster in the answers below.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't say that there's something wrong with it, but it is unusual.  The more customary formulation uses *bit* not *scrap*, and so would be *every **bit** as faithfully as I did*. But *scrap* and *bit* aren't really all that different, so the writer has switched them, for whatever reason.

To the modified question as to whether there should be a comma between the *every bit* part and the rest, consider these incremental reductions:

1. I will carry out her wishes in death every scrap as faithfully as I did when she was with me.
2. I will carry out her wishes in death every bit as faithfully as I did when she was with me.
3. I will carry out her wishes in death just as faithfully as I did when she was with me.
4. I will carry out her wishes in death as faithfully as I did when she was with me.
5. I will carry out her wishes as faithfully as I did when she was with me.
6. I will carry out her wishes as faithfully as before.

To me there is no convincing structural advantage in placing some sort of separator before *every scrap*:

7. I will carry out her wishes in death, every scrap as faithfully as I did when she was with me.
8. I will carry out her wishes in death — every scrap as faithfully as I did when she was with me.

But neither is it necessarily forbidden. Many issues of comma-placement like with the intention of the writer, not with some specific rule. It just depends how the writer wishes the sentence to be read.

What does not work for me is the solution suggested in comments:

9. I will carry out her wishes in death, every *scrap, as faithfully as I did when she was with me.

That second comma seems off. It makes me try to read this as an appositive, which doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you.

I understood. But shouldn't the "every scrap" part be between commas? Because it is an addition to the sentence - the sentence would still be right without them.

Comment: @DigiNinGravy Oh, I don't think so, but commas are something of a personal matter. Where were you thinking they might go?

Comment: I thought it would fit more (structure wise) like this :

"I will carry out her wishes in death, every scrap, as faithfully as I did when she was with me."

Comment: @DigiNinGravy I agree that the sentence needs some sort of separator  -  the "in death every scrap" reads oddly to me.  I'd suggest "I will carry out her wishes in death  -   every scrap as faithfully as I did when she was with me."

Comment: @DigiNinGravy No, you wouldn't put a comma after the word *scrap*. You should probably edit your question to include the part about the commas.

Comment: @DavidGarner Indeed, your suggestion reads better to me.

Comment: @DavidGarner I think you're right: *every scrap* modifies the comparative construction *as faithfully as ...*. But I don't agree that it requires a comma: that would mark "every scrap as faithfully..." as a supplement rather than the primary content of the utterance.

Comment: Just to reinforce that ***but it is unusual***, I'll point out that Google Books doesn't include a single instance of [every scrap as well as](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22every+scrap+as+well+as%22), but there are over 90 *thousand* instances of [every **bit** as well as](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22every+bit+as+well+as%22). For my money, whilst it's not "ungrammatical", OP's cited usage is totally "non-idiomatic".

Answer (score 3):

*Note: this answer was written for first version of the question which was focused on **every scrap**, before question was updated to pinpoint on the comma usage.*

The [previous lines](https://mcpl.monroe.lib.in.us/Mobile/BakerAndTaylor/Excerpt?ISBN=9781501128370&UPC=&position=1) are

> And although I have little faith that my life will ever again feel worthwhile, I still do not wish to throw it away. Aurelia may be gone, but she is not done with me yet. [...]

then the line in the question i.e.

> I will carry out her wishes in death every scrap as faithfully as I did when she was with me.

Maybe the author chose **scraps** as opposed to  **bits** the keep the theme of worthlessness or things that could be thrown away.

Maybe this is lit-crit not ELU.

Comment: Never thought of it in this way...

What do you mean by ELU?

Comment: @DigiNinGravy elu = this website. I was worried my answer was stepping into off-topic literary criticism subjects ... which was why I cut it short!

Comment: Your answer isn't literary criticism. I know this because I can understand it. Fight the self-censorship. The explanation helps to understand an unusual word choice that parallels an idiom. Also consider that the wording has the uncomfortable echo of *I will carry out her death wishes, every scrap [of them], as faithfully....* Upvote.

Comment: And I see the driveby downvoter, a curse upon this site, has delivered another stealthy discourtesy.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence, "every scrap" functions as an adverb modifying "as faithfully [etc.]" Grammatically, the construction is no different than "I will carry out her wishes in death just as faithfully as I did when she was with me." Just as you wouldn't put coins around "just" ("I will carry out her wishes in death, just, as faithfully as I did when she was with me."), you wouldn't put them around "every scrap."

If there's a question, the best thing is to consult a reputable style guide. The following rules-of-thumb will serve well in most cases, though, especially if no style guide is available.

- Read the sentence out loud. If the sentence sounds wrong with a pause, there probably shouldn't be a comma. (It may be fine to have one, but it probably isn't *needed*.)
- Generally, adverbs only get commas if the adverb is at the start of the sentence but modifying the main verb (as in this sentence) or if the adverbs are in a list (e.g, "He quickly, carefully, and secretly placed the book on the table.").

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the two things help much. Punctuation rules are matters of style, and the shoulds and shouldn'ts are a matter of conformance to a particular style guide. Pauses in spoken speech are an unreliable guide to the rules for written text. The *Chicago Manual of Style* advises that introductory adverbial clauses be followed by a comma, but for adverbial phrases, the comma may be omitted if the phrase is short or immediately precedes the verb. (*Mournfully came the sobs*).

Comment: @deadrat, I agree that pauses in speech have limitations in use, but the rule of thumb I've given works in most cases. It's not saying that every comma _will_ or _should_ have a pause in speech, not is it saying that commas should only be used if you would pause. But in _most_ places where there should be a comma, the pause will sound natural to a native speaker, even if he wouldn't put one there in his own speech. I agree that consulting a reputable style guide is the best option, but some things are common to any style  guide because they're conventions of the language (or of a variant)..

Comment: I'm afraid you're laboring under some misconceptions.  The conventions of style guides are the conventions of typography, not of the language.  These conventions are in place to guide the reader through written text, which is a different venue from the spoken word. I am not denying that comma placement in text often aligns with spoken pauses when the text is read aloud. I'm saying that this correlation makes a poor guide for the use of punctuation.